# Updating a dbms based on user input and existing dbms data

Tags: email, database

I have a php page which extracts data from a dbms which contains email addy.  This works.  It then displays the email addy and other stored data data.  The user then has the option of putting an "X" in a field designed in the php page called emailselected.  This also works.  I now want to update the dbms with the new field based on the stored email addy but the update statement doesn't work.  Please help.  This portion of the php file is here.

```
    include("db.php");
if (isset($_POST['ssubmit']))
    {
    $id_save = $test['id'];
    $emailselected_save = $_POST['emailselected'];
    $email_save = $test['email'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE emails SET selected='$emailselected_save' WHERE id = 'id'");
    echo "<input type='button' value='Email(s) sent' onclick='goBack()' />";
mysql_close($conn);
    } else {echo "hello";}
?>
</head>
<form method='post'>
    <div id='headd'>
    <br />
    <input type='button' value='Close this window without Sending' onclick='goBack()' />
    <input type='submit' name='ssubmit' id='ssubmit' value='Send Email Now!!!' />
    <p>Place an "X" in the emails you wish to send!!!</p>
    </div>
    <body>
        <br /><br/>

<?php
    include("db.php");  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE unsubscribe  != 'x' ORDER BY lastname ASC");
            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
?>
    <table border='1' width='78%'>
    <tr align=\"left\">
        <td width='4%'><font color='black'><input type='text' size='1' id='emailselected' name='emailselected' /></font></td>
        <td width='15%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['lastname']?></font></td>
        <td width='15%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['firstname']?></font></td>
        <td width='40%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['email']?></font></td>
        <td width='4%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['id']?></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
            }
?>
</form>
```

At the top of the form is an include statement.  This works because it extracts the email addy and displays it in the php file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "addy" is not an English word. Are you a six-year-old child? :-)

Comment: why are you being mean?  can you help me with my question or not?

Comment: Why yes, Dave, I certainly can :-) See my answer. In terms of being mean, that was not my intent, that humour is an Aussie thing and, while it's mostly directed at ourselves, it sometimes escapes to the rest of the world as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much limited to the following possibilities if the data didn't update:

- the statement failed; or
- the statement affected no rows; or
- the statement affected the *wrong* rows.

To find out which, you should check the return code from `mysql_query` to see if it failed or not:

```
$rc = mysql_query('my hovercraft is full of eels');
if (!$result) {
    die('What?: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

If it didn't fail, you should then check how many rows it affected with `mysql_affected_rows()`:

```
$num = mysql_affected_rows();
printf("Updated %d rows\n", $num);
```

Checking return values from functions that return them is good programming practice.

It might also be a good idea to output or log all those variables that you're using in the SQL statement to ensure they're what you think they are.

And, though it should go without saying by now, use of the `mysql_*` functions are [discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), you should be using [`mysqli_*` (or `PDO`)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

---

And I've only just noticed that your hierarchy of HTML elements doesn't seem quite right. You have effectively:

```
<head>
    :
</head>
<form>
    :
    <body>
        :
```

which doesn't gel for me. I'm not sure that `form` is valid *outside* of the body. According to the [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-html-element.html#the-html-element), the html element must contain:

> a head element followed by a body element.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Concerning the question, I am not that proficient at querying against databases.  How can I validate if the return code for the mysql_query failed or not?  Could you please be more specific as how to do that.  I'm a little slow this morning. LOL

Comment: No probs, @Dave, have a look at the update. I don't have a PHP environment at my current location but that should be close enough to what you need.

Comment: ok, I inserted your code and nothing.  I am thinking its something else.  I didn't even get the "What?:" or the printr results.  If you look at my original code at the submit button that starts the update process there may be a problem there.  I think it is not even getting to the isset ssubmit command for some reason.  I previously tried inserting an alert statement regardless of results and it didn't display either.  I am using "ssubmit" so it won'ty conflict with another submit statement i'm going to add to the form later.  I'm lost LOL

Comment: Maybe it has something to placement of the button in relation to the update statement or something like that.  I'm not sure.

Comment: @David, why is you form _outside_ of your body? I don't think that's a valid HTML doc.

Comment: good point, i went ahead and moved both the body and head to the very top of the page.  still it does not show any message you had me put in and does not update the database with an "x".

Comment: @David, you need to redo your question with the updated code.

Comment: I have now found that when someone answers a questions in here, the answer is not always clear.  This does not mean the answer is wrong or incomplete.  Just that I don't understand it because I am not familiar with that concept.  I am now taking a concenious of answers I receive and either fix my problem or research the concept of the answer to see if it actually applies.  This does not always help but its worth investigating to help eliminate repeaditly asking the same question.  Thanks for all your help.